# How do I conditionally prematurely end a while loop?

Tags: python, variables

```
nextround=True
#Reading from a file to a list for Songs
SongNamesList = []
myfile = open("Songnames.txt", "r")
endOfFile = False
while endOfFile == False:
  temp = myfile.readline() 
  temp = temp.strip()
  if not temp:
    endOfFile = True   
  else:
    SongNamesList.append(temp)
myfile.close()
#Reading from a file to a list for Artists
ArtistsList = []
myfile1 = open("Artists.txt", "r")
endOfFile = False
while endOfFile== False:
  temp = myfile1.readline() 
  temp = temp.strip()
  if not temp:
    endOfFile = True   
  else:
    ArtistsList.append(temp)
myfile1.close()
cont = True

#sets score to 0 at the start of the game
totalscore = 0

#Sets up continue variable to allow the user to stop the game if they want
while cont == True:
  
#Sets up guess count number to cut out after 3
  guesscount = 0
  
#Generates random artist and song
  randomindex = random.randint(0,len(ArtistsList)-1)
  Artist = [randomindex]
  a=(ArtistsList[randomindex])
  #print(a)
  b=(SongNamesList[randomindex])
  #print(b)
  answercount=0
  
#Works out if answer is correct problem  
  while answercount <=2:
      print(a[0:1])
      print(b[0:1])
      guess1 = input("What is the Artist name?")
      guess2=input("What is the Song name?")
      if guess1==a and guess2==b:
        print("Correct!")
        guesscount=guesscount+1
        print(guesscount)
      else:
        print("Incorrect! Please input another answer:")
        guesscount=guesscount+1
        print(guesscount)
        
#Works out the number of points given in turn for the guess count
  if guesscount==1:
      totalscore=totalscore+3
      print(totalscore)
      guesscount=0
      print("Your Score Is:",(totalscore))
  elif guesscount==2:
      totalscore=totalscore+1
      guesscount=0
      cont=True
      print("Your Score Is:", totalscore)
      print(totalscore)
  elif guesscount==3:
      print(None)
  elif guesscount>=4:
      print("The Song was",b)
      print("The Artist was",a)
      print("Your Score Is:", totalscore)
      print(totalscore)
  else:
      cont=False
      print("You have failed to Guess,your total score was:", totalscore)
      print("The Song was",b)
      print("The Artist was",a)
```

This is all the relevant code for the problem. I know that the problem lies in the variables for the score and how many points need to be added. The Code is for a music game where a player must guess the music title and artist name from only one letter of both, both the artists and the songs are in files that have been written to.

The problem as stated before is in how many points are added per guess so if the song and artist are guessed first try they get 3 points and so on, however it will repeat 3 times even if it is guessed correctly, this is where I have messed up as I have only created one variable for both the guess count to decide points and guess count to decide whether to continue the game.

How would I go about this? Ideally by changing as little of the current code as possible?

Answer (score 0):

As a minimal change fix you could put in a `break` after the answer has been correctly guessed to escape the while loop:

```
  if guess1==a and guess2==b:
    print("Correct!")
    guesscount=guesscount+1
    print(guesscount)
    break
```